# MASONERY LISTVIEW WITH YII2

Tags: listview, gridview, kendo-ui, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am working on yii2 advanced application i want to custum my index page from grid view to masonery list vieW(Like  : [KENDO UI](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/listview/index))

I don't know how to start , is any one can help me and show me the steps for doing this.